# chromedriver version 123.0.6312.59 not downloaded by webdriver manager

Tags: webdriver-manager

my chrome browser version is 123.0.6312.59  and i'm trying to use web driver manager in my selenium code but it gives error
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: '

```
java.io.OutputStream org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.getLogOutput(java.lang.String)'
```

and i can't found a binary for chrome driver 123.0.6312.59 in the official website the latest is 123.0.6312.58

my pom file

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.18.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: You can check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77614587/where-can-i-find-chromedriver-119/77614979#77614979
Although, as I can see, there is still no binary for your version.

Comment: @MilosStojanovic thanks for your reply but the mentioned question is for another older version , but for this specific version i can see that it did't exists

Answer (score 0):

Change the dependency to below

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>4.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```